# Fetch POST with credtials same origin security error (Express & React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, cors

I'm trying to test a login path from React hitting a route on a Express API; the request is a POST using fetch like so:

```js
const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/login`, {
  method: "POST",
  mode: "same-origin",
  credentials: "include",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    email,
    password,
    role,
  }),
})
```

On the API I am using Express cors middleware with this config:

```
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: true }));
```

When I try to make the request on Postman everything is fine, but on the browser I get this error:

```
Security Error: Content at http://localhost:1234/login may not load data from http://localhost:3001/login.
```

Am I missing some headers on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

In your frontend `package.json` file, you should proxy the URL, by adding the following line (which lets the frontend know to proxy API request to the server port):

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"
```

Then in your React component, you don't have to hard-code the root URL, you can just do:

```js
await fetch(`/login`, {
...
})
```

Comment: Is this something that comes with create-react-app? I'm not using that.

Comment: No, proxy is a webpack-dev-server feature